# In resharper 5.1 how do you turn back on the code inspection to offer to covert foreach loop to linq expressions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-5.1

I'm not sure this is the right forum if it's not please feel free to move it...

In in VS2010 , in Resharper 5.1 how do you turn back on the code inspection to offer to covert foreach loop to linq expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ReSharper->Options` window, go to `Code Inspection->Inspection Severity`.

You can change the inspection options for each item there.

Comment: I looked there amny times and was not able to find it, like it was mising though it should be in 5.01 which I was running. I upgraded to 6.0 and it reappeard and now works.

Comment: @EricBrown-Cal I think that code inspection was added in v6, now that I look at it, which would explain why it was "missing" in 5.x